# Split/Second Graphical Glitch during Alternate Routes

Tags: pc, split-second

I have a physical copy of *Split/Second* ([Steam Page - for reference only](http://store.steampowered.com/app/297860/SplitSecond/),  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split/Second)).

For some reason, I've been encountering a glitch where the alternate route(s) appear to have been triggered, but they aren't.

When I attempt to drive through them, I end up falling through surfaces (streets, bridges, etc.) and crashing. The animation(s) for the routes also change (almost instantaneously) as I drive up to them. It even happens when I purposefully trigger the alternate route sometimes, which is quite annoying.

What could be causing this? How do I fix this?

Comment: On steam, Id say try a repair or a redownload. Played on xbox disk and never encountered the problem which makes me think of a corrupt file issue.

Comment: Sorry if I caused any confusion - I meant physical copy. I installed it via DVD, so I guess I just run 'Repair Installation'?